# lilypad works with wrong baudrate

Tags: serial

I wrote a simple code on lillypad with fdti module as below:

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(57600);
}
void loop(){
 Serial.println("ddd");
 delay(500);
}
```

but it gives wrong characters at serial port window of arduino ide at 57600 baudrate. But I changed baudrate to 115200 at same window it gives right string as "ddd". Other baudrates do the same thing. What is the solution or where is the problem. I couldnt understand why baudrate shift occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The baud rate shift occurs because of a mismatch between the speed your program thinks the chip is running at and the speed the chip is actually running at.

You may also have noticed that `delay(500)` is too fast and actually lasts as long as `delay(250)` would.

By the numbers involved it looks like the board is running twice as fast (115200 / 57600 = 2) as your board definition says it is - maybe you're using an 8MHz definition for a 16MHz board, or a 1MHz definition for a 2MHz board, etc.

Make sure you have the right board definition selected in the IDE for your board.